# Analogue of examspace in xsim

Tags: exsheets, xsim

I am looking to recreate what `\examspace` command does in `exsheets` with its successor `xsim` package. The default seems to be to leave blank lines (ouch!!).

Here is what I thought might work (but doesn't):

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{xsim} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{exercise} 
Question 1 \blank[blank-style=#1,width=5\linewidth]{}
\end{exercise} 
\end{document}
```

I tried many variants of this but nothing seems to work. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`blank-style={\phantom{#1}}` seems to work.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{xsim} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{exercise}[subtitle={\texttt{phantom} look}]
Question 1 \blank[blank-style={\phantom{#1}},width=5\linewidth]{}
\end{exercise} 
\begin{exercise}[subtitle={Default look}] 
Question 2 \blank[width=5\linewidth]{}
\end{exercise} 
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Thank you so much! As always, it feels easy once you see it... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply that spacing uniformliy, you can also use `post-hook`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
    exercise/post-hook = {\vspace*{8em} }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Question 1
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
    Question 2
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]